# Passing data from one class to another

Tags: java, android

In class B, I have the following method:

```
public String sendPlayerDataMethod() {
  String testt = "thissss is for testing";
  /*** 
  Intent sendPlayerData = new Intent(this, FullPlayerList.class);
  sendPlayerData.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, testt);
  startActivity(sendPlayerData);
  ***/
 return testt;
}
```

In class A, I want to simply call this method. I thought `ClassB.sendPlayerDataMethod()` would do the trick, but when I'm typing it out IntelliJ doesn't seem to pick it up.

Both classes are public as well...
I want to call that method and then assign the return value to a var in ClassA...

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit and add the code that isn't doing what you expect? It sounds like you're trying to treat `sendPlayerDataMethod` as if it was static by calling on the class rather than an instance of `ClassB`.

Comment: make the method static so that it can accessed as ClassB.functionName()

public static String functionName() {}

Comment: How are you accessing ClassB.sendPlayerDataMethod()? Did you create an object first?

Answer (score 1):

Your method is actually correct, there's no problem with it. The most likely reason you're still getting this behaviour is because of the way you are referencing the method (from class A). There are two approaches to solving this problem:

- The first approach **(and also the faster one)** is to make your `sendPlayerDataMethod()` static and then referencing it like this in class A:

  ```
  ClassB.sendPlayerDataMethod();
  ```
- The other option is to make it non-static. In this case, you have to create an object of class B before you can use the method. Like this:

  ```
  ClassB b = new ClassB();
  b.sendPlayerDataMethod();
  ```

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to pass information from one activity to another activity.

The common way is to create an Intent in class A (like in your commented code) and receive the intent by accessing the information about `onCreate()` method from `savedInstance` in class B.

Don't code such dirty tricks like static attributes and stuff. Follow the 
[Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {
    ...
    public void sendPlayerDataMethod() {
        String test = "thissss is for testing";
        Intent sendPlayerData = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        sendPlayerData.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, test);
        startActivity(sendPlayerData);
    }
    ...
}

public class ActivityB extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String test = savedInstanceState.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        Log.i("MyApp", test); // log your String in LogCat
    }

}
```

(This code is just developed right here in SO without IDE so no guarantee)

Comment: Excellent point and description of my issue. The two classes are an activity each but I just tired to create a class on its own an then try call the method, it still could not resolve it.
I've done it the way you have typed up before and that works.
All I really wanted to do was call the method else where.

Answer (score 0):

In class A:

- Non-static way:

  ```
  B b = new B();
  String data = b.sendPlayerDataMethod();
  ```
- Static way:

  ```
  String data = B.sendPlayerDataMethod();
  // Set the sendplayerdatamethod to static
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just tried it up it but it still says "Cannot resolve symbol sendPlayerData.

Comment: @Trigger Make the method static. Add "static" before "string".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the method is static like this:

```
public static String sendPlayerDataMethod() {
 String testt = "thissss is for testing";
 /*** Intent sendPlayerData = new Intent(this, FullPlayerList.class);
  sendPlayerData.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, testt);
  startActivity(sendPlayerData);***/
 return testt;
}
```

Then you can call it from **class A** like this:

```
classB.sendPlayerDataMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just tried it up it but it still says "Cannot resolve symbol sendPlayerData.